# program using vector to find equilibrium index fails

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a program that finds and prints out the equilibrium index of a sequence  (an index such that the sum of elements at lower indexes is equal to the sum of elements at higher indexes). But I get the following error message:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'e' is being used without being initialized.
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int equi( vector<int> Vec , int index );

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

 vector<int> A( 5 );

 A[ 0 ] = 7;
 A[ 1 ] = 2;
 A[ 2 ] = -4;
 A[ 3 ] = 6;
 A[ 4 ] = 3;

 int e;

 equi( A, e );

 system( "PAUSE" );
}


int equi( vector<int> Vec , int index )
{
 index = 0;
 int leftSum = 0;
 int rightSum = 0;

 for ( int j = 0 ; j < Vec.size() ; j++ )
 {

    for ( int i = index + 1 ; i < Vec.size() ; i++ )
        {
            rightSum = rightSum + Vec[ i ];
        };

    if ( leftSum == rightSum )  return index;
    else
        {
            leftSum = leftSum + Vec[ index ];
            index++;
        };

 }

 return -1;
}
```

Can someone please help me find out what I am doing wrong? Why would I need to initialize `e` when it is declared integer both in the `main` and the function declaration and definition???

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

```
int e = 0;
equi( A, e );
```

e should be initialized to a value, otherwise it is passed (by value) to the function `equi`.  This means that the function `equi` takes a copy of the value (e.g. any changes to `e` inside `equi` won't be visible outside).

Answer (score 2):

The way your code is right now, `e` stays uninitialized and you pass a copy of it to `equi`. You want to do one of these:

```
void equi(vector<int> Vec, int & index);
...
int e;
equi(A, e);
```

or

```
int equi(vector<int> Vec);
...
int e = equi(A);
```

In the first method, your `equi` function will actually change the index you pass to it. Right now you're passing by value, and thus give `equi` a copy of your `e` variable, which then of course doesn't change. Make your function's return type `void`, and change the final `return -1` to `index = -1`.

In the second method, just remove the `index` argument from `equi` and make it local. Just assign the return value to `e`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ built-in types such as int are not zero initialized. This means the value of e is undefined when you use it. `int e = 0` will fix this.